# Compute the indefinite integral $I=\int y^{-a}(1−y)^{b-1} dy$ or $I=\int_{d}^1 y^{-a}(1−y)^{b-1} dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I need to calculate the indefinite integral $I=\int y^{-a}(1−y)^{b-1} dy$, where $a$, $b$ are REAL NUMBERS and $b>0$.
(my goal is to determine the definite integral $I=\int_{d}^1 y^{-a}(1−y)^{b-1} dy$, where $d<1$).
Thanks !

Comment: You might find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) of some help.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int_d^1 {y^{ - a} \left( {1 - y} \right)^{b - 1} dy}  = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \int_d^1 {y^{r - 1} \left( {1 - y} \right)^{b - 1} dy} ,\,\,\,\,\,\,a < 0,\,\,\text{setting}\,\,a = 1 - r,r > 1 \\ 
 \frac{1}{b}\left( {1 - d} \right)^b ,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,a = 0 \\ 
 \int_d^1 {y^{r - 1} \left( {1 - y} \right)^{b - 1} dy} ,\,\,\,\,\,\,a > 0,\,\,\text{setting}\,\,a = 1 - r,r < 1 \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
\end{align}
So that, you can continue with incomplete beta function.

**Another method:**

**Case 1:If $a=0$ and $b>0$**, then $$I=
\int_d^1 {\left( {1 - y} \right)^{b - 1} dy}  = \frac{1}{b}\left( {1 - d} \right)^b 
$$

**Case 2:If $b=0$ and $a>0$ and $a\ne1$**, then $$
\int_d^1 {y^{ - a} dy}  = \frac{{1 - d^{1 - a} }}{{1 - a}}
$$

**Case 3:If $b>0$ with $b\ne1$ and $a>0$, $-1<d<1$**, then the binomial series 
\begin{align}
\left( {1 + x} \right)^\alpha   = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( \begin{array}{l}
 \alpha  \\ 
 k \\ 
 \end{array} \right)x^k } , \alpha \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\},\,\,\, \forall x \in (-1,1),
\end{align}
where $$
\left( \begin{array}{l}
 \alpha  \\ 
 k \\ 
 \end{array} \right) = \frac{{\alpha \left( {\alpha  - 1} \right)\left( {\alpha  - 2} \right) \cdots \left( {\alpha  - \left( {k - 1} \right)} \right)}}{{k!}}$$

may be used by setting $\alpha:=b-1$, $(b\ne1)$, the interval $(d,1)\subseteq (-1,1)$, we have

\begin{align}
\left( {1 - y} \right)^{b - 1}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {b - 1}  \\
   k  \\
\end{array}} \right)y^k } 
\end{align}
Multiplying both sides by $y^{ - a} $ and then integrating both sides with respect to $y$, we get
\begin{align}
&\int_d^1 {y^{ - a} \left( {1 - y} \right)^{b - 1} dy}  
\\
&= \int_d^1 {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {b - 1}  \\
   k  \\
\end{array}} \right)y^{k - a} } } \right)dy} 
\\
&= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {b - 1}  \\
   k  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\int_d^1 {y^{k - a} dy} } \right)} 
\\ 
&= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {b - 1}  \\
   k  \\
\end{array}} \right)\frac{{1 - d^{k - a + 1} }}{{k - a + 1}}}, \,\,\,\, \text{with} \,\,
a \ne k + 1 
\end{align}
where, we used the fact that the series converges uniformly for all $y \in (d,1)\subseteq (-1,1)$.

We note that the condition $a\ne k+1$ is equivalent to say that $a \notin \mathbb{N}$ i.e., $a\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$. One more point, If $d<-1$ the series diverges so that we cannot integrate. All these additional conditions should be added.

Comment: $b >0$ (I have edited the question)

Comment: My problem fits with the third case $a>0$ and $r<1$ (but $r<0$). I think that the Incomplete beta function is not defined for negative parameters

Comment: yes, not defined for negatives. What you have tried? I will keep thinking!

Comment: I have tried to decompose the integral : $\int_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{d} $and made some variable changes, then I have used this [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type) for the first integral but for the second it doesn't work ..

Comment: In this case, $a>0$ we have $I:=
\int_d^1 {\frac{{\left( {1 - y} \right)^{b - 1} }}{{y^a }}dy} 
$, since $b>0$ then $b-1>-1$ if we assume that $a=b-1$ then done. If $a>b-1$ then  $a=b-1+q$, $q>0$ so that $
I = \int_d^1 {\frac{{\left( {1 - y} \right)^{b - 1} }}{{y^{b - 1 + q} }}dy}  = \int_d^1 {y^{1 - b - q} \left( {1 - y} \right)^{b - 1} dy} $ (try!?). Finally, if $0<a<b-1$, then $b-1=a+q \implies a=b-1-q$, and $
I = \int_d^1 {\frac{{\left( {1 - y} \right)^{b - 1} }}{{y^{b - 1 - q} }}dy}  = 
\int_d^1 {y^{q - 1} \left( {1 - y} \right)^{b - 1} dy} 
 $

Comment: Of course, I assumed $a=b-1>0$ and $a>b-1>0$. By the way when i saw your q? i thought like you with hypergeometric!? but it doesn't work

Comment: The formula is for the domain of integral $[0,1]$. that's why I have decomposed the integral in 2 terms and try to have, for each, the same domain which is $[0,1]$

Comment: My answer is updated, check!

Answer (score 0):

HINT use integration by parts where function to be differentiated is (1-y)^b-1 and integrable function is y^-a

YOu have reduction formula setup .

then when you get values of m and n .